# Selenium Python Pytest testing a web page using parametrized tests. ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation

The same test runs as expected with all the parameters except '31' which results in ElementClickInterceptedException

Basically, this test has to check the max and minimum input length for the user name field and as an expected outcome the element which css selector is `p[class="validation-message ng-star-inserted"]` has to appear ONLY if the length is not accepted and the assert message appears in console where you run this code

my test file:

```
import pytest
import sys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pages.main_page import MainPage

link = "https://rozetka.com.ua/"
test_len_list = [str(num) for num in range(0,100)] 
test_len_list = ['a' for num in range(0, 33)] 
test_len_str = "".join(test_len_list)

class TestRegisterPage():
    @pytest.mark.len
@pytest.mark.parametrize('num', [0, 1, 2, 31, 32, 64, 128,256])
def test_field_username_len(self, browser, num):
    # is it functional testing if I need to make a sequence of steps before reaching to the element I need to test
    # Because if some step from this sequence won't work the entire test fails

    if num <= 0:
        field_value = ''
    else:
        test_len_list = ['в' for b in range(0,
                                            num)]  
        field_value = "".join(test_len_list)
    page = MainPage(browser, link)

    #check if internet connection is present
    if not has_connection(page.browser):
        print('No Internet connection, aborted!')
        page.browser.quit()
    else:
        page.open()

        log_in_btn = page.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class='header__button ng-star-inserted'][type='button']")
        log_in_btn.click()
        register_btn = page.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class='auth-modal__register-link ng-star-inserted']")
        register_btn.click()
        # time.sleep(3)
        username_input = page.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id='registerUserName']")
        username_input.send_keys(field_value)
        time.sleep(3)
        assert page.is_element_present(
            'p[class="validation-message ng-star-inserted"]') == False, "Lenght does not satisfy the requirements"
```

my MainPage file:

```
from .base_page import BasePage
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class MainPage(BasePage):

    def click_alert(self):
        main_window = self.browser.window_handles[0]
        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
        alert = self.browser.switch_to.alert
        alert.accept()
        self.browser.switch_to.window(main_window)

    def find_login_button(self):
        return self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class='header__button ng-star-inserted'][type='button']")

    def find_register_button(self):
        return self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class='auth-modal__register-link ng-star-inserted']")
```

my BasePage file:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


class BasePage:
    def __init__(self, browser, url, timeout=30):
        self.browser = browser
        self.url = url
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(timeout)

    def open(self):
        self.browser.get(self.url)

    def is_element_present(self, css_selector):
        try:
            self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False
        return True
```

Screenshot of test result for a value '31' which is of type int
[test case param 31](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g2gw.png)

Comment: Please share the screenshot of error ElementClickInterceptedException, it will prompt which element is blocking the element you are trying to click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using JS click?

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("myid")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Replace your click function with the above and try.

```
log_in_btn = page.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class='header__button ng-star-inserted'][type='button']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", log_in_btn )

register_btn = page.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class='auth-modal__register-link ng-star-inserted']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", register_btn)
```

Comment: yeah, thanks! It works fine) However, with this approach - one can overlook some of the bugs while testing the functionality